# Non-commutative expansion of brackets (Python)

Tags: python, sympy, commutativity

I wanted to ask whether there is a method to expand brackets in Python non-commutatively. For example,
`INPUT (x+y)**2, OUTPUT x**2 + x*y + y*x + y**2`,

instead of the usual output `x**2 + 2*x*y + y**2`.

SymPy gives this commutative output, but I have seen that a non-commutative output is possible in Mathematica (NonCommutativeMultiply). Could anyone suggest some Python code which will expand brackets non-commutatively? It would be a big help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create non-commutative symbols:

```py
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols("x, y", commutative=False)
expr = (x+y)**2
expr = expr.expand()
print(expr)
# out: x*y + x**2 + y*x + y**2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with "sympy.nc"

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.nc import NC

x, y = symbols('x y')
nc_x = NC(x)
nc_y = NC(y)

expression = nc_x * nc_y + nc_y * nc_x + nc_y ** 2 + nc_x ** 2
print(expression)
```